# Jenkins file system on Linux server VS Jenkins EXECUTOR_NUMBER variable

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, centos7

I have Jenkins on Centos server with only one job calls "HOMEPAGE".
I would like to run this job in parallel, this is why I setup 5 executors for master node.

[image]

This "HOMEPAGE" job running java program that creates some folders and files that I need to use. So I need to know the fool path to files on server that was creating during this job.
Problem start when I run this job in parallel.

For first build Jenkins would assigne path: `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HOMEPAGE/` and `executor_number=2`

For second build: `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HOMEPAGE@2/` and `executor_number=4`

For third: `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HOMEPAGE@3/` and `executor_number=1`

For fourth: `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HOMEPAGE@4/` and `executor_number=3`

After execution I could see this folders on server:

[image]

As you can see, the number of the HOMEPAGE folder is not consistent with executor_number variable in Jenkins.

How could I get information from Jenkins about where it saving results in current build? Whether it HOMEPAGE@2 or HOMEPAGE@4 folder? I need this information for my java program.

Here is fragments from Console Output:

First build:

```
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HOMEPAGE/pom.xml -PHomepage -Djob_name=HOMEPAGE -Dexecutor_number=2
```

Third build:

```
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HOMEPAGE@3/pom.xml -PHomepage -Djob_name=HOMEPAGE -Dexecutor_number=1
```

Comment: Did you check the environment variables set by Jenkins? There should be an job related path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment variable 'WORKSPACE' will always contain the proper path, including any `@<n>` suffix.